# Microsoft Edge extension

Tags: azure, microsoft-edge

I am creating an extension for Microsoft Edge and have connected it to an azure server, However when I run the extension in edge I get a popup message which states I must use a different app from the Microsoft store. I know that this is not a server error because the Chrome version connects to the server without an error. The Code I am using for the edge extension is as follows:

```js
function openPage() {

 browser.windows.create({
    url: //SERVER URL HERE,
    left: (window.screenLeft - 300),
    top:  (window.screenTop - 250),
    type:"popup",
    width: 850,
    height: 650

});
  
}

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(openPage);
```

Answer (score -1):

This mostly happens when Edge tries to associate a particular URI scheme to a Pluggable protocol. You can read about this here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb266527(v=vs.85).aspx

To help you further I will need to know the server URL

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20009151)

Comment: Actually I wanted to add the above answer as a comment. As I didnt have enough reputation at that time I went ahead answering it. Thanks!